# When to use SafeArrayAccessData to lock a SAFEARRAY

Tags: c++, com, variant, safearray

I'm having a question about when it is necessary to use SafeArrayAccessData to lock a SAFEARRAY, which is passed by managed code.
Here is our code. The VARIANT is passed by managed code, with a string array. During code review, somebody suggest to use SafeArrayAccessData/SafeArrayUnAccessData. But he is not sure about why and what's the benefit. Can you share some of your experiences? Thanks!

```
STDMETHODIMP Base::Method1(VARIANT values, VARIANT_BOOL result)
{
    CComSafeArray<BSTR> ids;
    ids.Attach(values.parray);

    unsigned int size = ids.GetCount();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
    // use ids[i] here
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, always :)  You need it to get a reference to the array content.

But you use a friendly C++ wrapper class.  The CComSafeArray<> template already does this for you so you should not help.  It uses SafeArrayLock() in the Attach() method, that also returns a pointer to the array content like SafeArrayAccessData() does.  And automatically unlocks with its destructor, it runs at the end of your method.  Locking otherwise ensures that the array access is thread-safe and cannot be deleted while you are accessing it.  There is little danger of that in your existing code, but this squarely fits the better-safe-than-sorry principles of Automation.

Comment: Thanks! And you said, my code is little danger than using SafeArrayAccessData. Do you mean the latter is a thread safe implementation?

Comment: And I have one more question? As green hand of Automation, I'm wondering when I pass this array from manage code to native, what happened? Who allocate the memory of the VARIANT formal argument, who copied the data and who release it? Can you give a hint as well? Thanks!

Comment: It was the CLR's job to marshal the array to a SAFEARRAY.  It is stored in the COM interop heap (CoTaskMemAlloc).  It is going to destroy the array after the call so it you'll need to copy the array data if you want to keep it around.  Not sure what happens if you keep it locked, I assume that will deadlock.

Comment: To Hans and all other experts: I think there is no need to lock or unlock but that it is absolutely necessary to call  `ids.Detach()` before `ids` goes out of scope since otherwise the `ids` destructor would destroy `values.parray` which it it not allowed to do.